# recalculate centroids kmeans in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to implement an ids under matlab using kmeans and I had a small problem I would like to recalculate the centroids of the new clusters I have tried to get the code of kmeans.m from package matlab to get the function and I got this:
**%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%**

```
function [centroids, counts] = gcentroids(X, index, clusts, dist)
%GCENTROIDS Centroids and counts stratified by group.
p = size(X,1);
num = length(clusts);

centroids = NaN(p,num,'like',X);
counts = zeros(1,num,'like',X);

for i = 1:num
    members = (index == clusts(i));
    if any(members)
       counts(i) = sum(members);
       switch dist
           case {'sqeuclidean','cosine','correlation'}
              centroids(:,i) = sum(X(:,members),2) / counts(i);
      end
    end
end
end
```

Comment: What is your question? Is there something wrong with MATLAB's implementation?

Comment: the question is how i recalculate the centroids of a new clusters ???